# How to minimize the font loading delay?

Tags: css, webfonts

I tried Google Lighthouse and it pointed me to an article for how to load fonts without delay:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display

I am using Open Sans which I used to load like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

The article had an example which I tried to use instead:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-display: block;
  src: local('Open Sans'), url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans) format('woff2');
}
```

It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Found it. I must keep the `font-family: "Open Sans"` which I thought was not used any more. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: on which browser have you test your css?

Comment: Open `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans` in your browser and tell us if that looks like binary woff2 font data to you …

Comment: @Sfili_81 Chrome.

Comment: @04FS I know very little about fonts. What should I put for `format`?

Comment: This is the URL of the stylesheet you get from Google, not of an individual font file. The actual font file URLs can be found in there.

Comment: Yes, but what should I use for `format`? It seems like the fonts in there are `woff2` and that the syntax I use works, but I have no idea whether it is correct.

Comment: @04FS Hm, you are right. It does not work. I get the error `Failed to decode downloaded font`. Obviously because of what you told me.

Comment: I think this helps me: https://css-tricks.com/dont-just-copy-the-font-face-out-of-google-fonts-urls/

Comment: You could just copy&paste the whole `@font-face` declaration (for whichever font variant[s] you need) directly from that stylesheet …

Comment: @04FS Yes, I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the speech marks "", what you want is here:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-display: block;
  src: local('Open Sans'), url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans") format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan, but I don't think the specs say you need them (maybe they are allowed?) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face