# Menu jumping and scaling when clicking

Tags: html, css

I have problems with the menu in my header at https://www.selmasvensson.com/. It is jumping around and scaling up when clicking on the links. The header loads from a dreamweaver template except in the first index page. I made the site years ago and can't really remember why I'm not using the template for the index but I know there was some problem. Anyway, the jumping problem occurs on all pages, template or no template, and has been there since I made the it. I remember I tried a lot of things back then but couldn't fix it. I was a newbie then and even more now so please excuse any crazy code or questions. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: No it is not working as said and is perfect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this occurs because the fonts/images aren't loaded immediately. This is called Content-Shifting.

Something like ajax loading can help: https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/

Otherwise you can try to minimize the font loading delay: [How to minimize the font loading delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707245/how-to-minimize-the-font-loading-delay)